# Using kazupon/vue-i18n inside a state of Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, translation, vuex, vue-i18n

**Using https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n for localization**

> Vue.t() || $t() || trans() receive a string which is a key to be translated by vue-i18n

Hey guys! I'am trying the following code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  task: {
    status: [
      { id: 'pending', name: Vue.t('pending') },
      { id: 'done', name: 'Done' }
    ]
  }
}
```

That is my state.js which is the state of my VUEX! When I try to use the Vue.t function I have the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _vue2.default.t is not a function

#### My solution (which I don't think it's the best one also good for performance)

Let my **state.js** like that:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  task: {
    status: [
      { id: 'pending', name: 'pending' },
      { id: 'done', name: 'done' }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I've done the following getters (vuex getter)

```js
import { map } from 'lodash'
import { trans } from 'utils/helpers/translation' // helper for Vue.t(string)

export const getTaskStatus = ({ task }) => map(task.status, (obj) => {
  return { id: obj.id, name: trans(obj.name) }
})
```

Anyone knows how is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [vuex-i18n](https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n) library, it does what you are trying to do out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

1- main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import App from './App';
import { store } from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

2- App.vue: here I used buttons to change languages:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ "index.title" | translate }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $t("index.content", {"type": "nice"}) }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ "home.title" | translate }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $t("home.content", {"type": "nice"}) }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ "product.title" | translate }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $t("product.content", {"type": "nice"}) }}</p>
        <p>{{ $t("product.unit", {"type": "nice"}) }}</p>
      </div>
      <button @click="setLang('fa')">پارسی</button>
      <button @click="setLang('en')">English</button>
      <button @click="setLang('ar')">العربیه</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setLang(lang) {
      this.$store.dispatch("changeCulture", lang);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("changeCulture", "en");
  }
};
</script>
```

3-store > index.js: here I tried to use sore, mutation and actions to change local:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import vuexI18n from 'vuex-i18n';
import translationsEn from '../locals/en.json';
import translationsFa from '../locals/fa.json';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fallback: 'en',
    locale: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    setCulture(state, payload) {
      state.locale = payload
      Vue.i18n.set(state.locale);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    changeCulture({ commit }, payload, adad) {
      commit('setCulture', payload)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    language(state) {
      return state.locale
    }
  }
})

Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);

Vue.i18n.add('en', translationsEn);
Vue.i18n.add('fa', translationsFa);

Vue.i18n.set('fa')
```

4- en.json / fa.json : some may ask for it:

```
{
  "index": {
    "title": "Hello",
    "content": "This is some {type} content"
  },
  "home": {
    "title": "About us",
    "content": "Node developing team"
  },
  "product": {
    "title": "Product",
    "content": "Select one product",
    "unit": "unit"
  }
}
```

... 4- fa.json is :

```
{
  "index": {
    "title": "سلام",
    "content": "به دنیای کد خوش آمدید"
  },
  "home": {
    "title": "درباره ما",
    "content": "تیم برنامه نویسی نود"
  },
  "product": {
    "title": "محصولات",
    "content": "یک محصول را انتخاب کنید",
    "unit": "واحد شمارش"
  }
}
```

And it works like a charm.